# Common Digital Twin Model for Twins with different properties

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-digital-twins

In our factory environment, we have multiple IoT Devices (Machines, Sensors, etc.) that send different metrics. Also among machines and sensors, these types of metrics can differ. I want a system where the digital twins for these devices are created automatically based on the metrics they send. Do I now have to create a unique model for each device or is it somehow possible to use a "general" model template, where twins can have the same model but different properties?

Comment: [Azure IoT Digital Twins client library for .NET](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.DigitalTwins.Core/1.0.0-preview.2/index.html) and [azure-sdk-for-net - digital twins](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/digitaltwins)

Comment: [Manage Azure Digital Twins models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/how-to-manage-model), [Monitor Azure Digital Twins with metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/how-to-monitor-metrics) and [Learn about twin models and how to define them in Azure Digital Twins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/concepts-models)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All twins of the same model share the same properties, so in your case, you might need to create a model per device type. If the telemetry differs per device for the same device type, you could consider making a model for that device type with a superset of all the properties.

Azure Digital Twins Models also support inheritance, which could be useful when creating a model per device type.

There is currently no support for model-less twins or creating them based on the input metrics.

Comment: Thank you, good to know. My plan is now to create models with "supersets" of properties, so data packages of similar shape are considered just in one model. For devices of the same "type" but substantially different properties, I will create seperate models based on "iot-device-category" metadata, which is sent with every datapackage.